# How to prevent from tabbing to a UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

If you connect a hardware keyboard to an iOS device (or simulate one in the simulator) you can hit the `Tab` key to jump between UITextFields. It so happens I have one instance in a range of `UITextField`s that I do not want the user to tab to, but only want to set as the first responder from code.

Is there a way to prevent the Tab from giving it first responder status, *without overriding* UITextField?

Comment: Try `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` (see [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html)).

Comment: Tsss. Hadn't thought of that. If you care to put it in an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` (of [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldBeginEditing%3a) protocol) to conditionally allow/disallow editing.